# C# Deserialization - Is it safe to catch TargetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, deserialization, targetinvocationexception

I am using BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize some objects. The structure of those object is as follows:

```
[Serializable()]
public class SerializableObject : ISerializable
{
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("SomeProperty", SomeProperty);
        // similar for other properties
    }

    public SerializableObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.SomeProperty = (SomePropertyClass)info.GetValue("SomeProperty", typeof(SomePropertyClass));
        // similar for other properties
    }
}
```

I have noticed that when I try to deserialize an object, a TargetInvocation exception is thrown if the "SomeProperty" entry cannot be found (for example, because it was renamed or deleted). Since I intend to change the properties of SerializableObject class in future, I was thinking of catching the exception and setting the value of the problematic property to some default value instead of crashing my application, like this:

```
public SerializableObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    try
    {
        this.SomeProperty = (SomePropertyClass)info.GetValue("SomeProperty", typeof(SomePropertyClass));
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException)
    {
        this.SomeProperty = SomePropertyClass.DefaultValue;
    }
}
```

As we all know, catching exceptions that you don't know how or cannot handle is a bad practice, so I'm asking whether it's safe to catch it in this place? Can the same exception be thrown for any other reason (that I don't know and therefore shouldn't handle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `TargetInvocationException` is **not** listed in the set of exceptions you should expect from that method ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.getvalue.aspx)) I would say it is wrong to try to handle that. A better approach is to loop on the names it *does* have, and pick the ones you expected:

```
    foreach(SerializationEntry entry in info)
    {
        switch(entry.Name)
        {
            case "Foo": //...   
            case "Bar": //...
        }
    }
```

Or... use a less fussy serializer ;p

(btw, the above uses the alternative `foreach` handling based on a typed enumerator and `GetEnumerator()` method; it doesn't implement `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>`, but... it doesn't have to; you can use `foreach` without that)

Comment: DataContractSerializer or something else?

Comment: @Ritch I could *settle* for `DataContractSerializer` - it is contract based, at least, which is a big step forwards. I'd almost always reach for protobuf-net, though - but I am somewhat biased there.

Comment: @Marc - Is protobuf-net still in beta? Would you advocate its use in production code at the moment? - pretend to be unbiased ;)

Comment: @David oh, v1 has been "out of beta" for *years*; v2 is certainly production safe (we use it here *millions* of times a day) - there are, however, a few rarely-used, niche methods that *most people* won't miss, but aren't fully recreated yet - *that* is all it is waiting on.

Answer (score 4):

A `TargetInvokationException` should have an `InnerException` which will give you more information. I'd suggest that you check the inner in the catch block and rethrow if the situation is simply a missing property.